# Using Offset in Firestore REST API queries

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to skip the first N values to implement pagination.
For example, page 1 returns results from 1-10, If I set the offset to 10, then the first 10 results will be skipped and I get 11-20 in page2.

**What am I trying to do?**

1. Set offset so that the first N values are skipped.
2. Do this with a REST API

**Request Body:**

```json
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
      {
        "collectionId": "play",
        "allDescendants": true
      }
    ],
    "where": {
      "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
          "fieldPath": "tags"
        },
        "op": "array_contains",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "charlie"
        }
      }
    }
    
}
  "offset":30,
}
```

**What error do I get?**

```json
[{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\n   }\n    }\n    \n}\n  \"offset\":30,\n}\n                    ^",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}]
```

PS: If there is a better way to implement pagination in firestore queries, please advice me on the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the format of the JSON representation for a [`StructuredQuery`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery?authuser=2&hl=en) you'll see that `offset` needs to be an element of the `StructuredQuery` object.

So you need to pass the following payload:

```
{
  "from": [
    {
      "collectionId": "play",
      "allDescendants": true
    }
  ],
  "where": {
    "fieldFilter": {
      "field": {
        "fieldPath": "tags"
      },
      "op": "array_contains",
      "value": {
        "stringValue": "charlie"
      }
    }
  },
  "offset": 30
}
```